# Repeat header on every page with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I have a problem to repeat header of the page on every page
using [Dompdf Wrapper for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). Anyone can help with simple example?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic example but I guess you can explore this further to match your requirement.

```
<style>
/** Define now the real margins of every page in the PDF **/
body {
    margin-top: 2cm;
    margin-left: 2cm;
    margin-right: 2cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
}

/** Define the header rules **/
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0cm;
    left: 0cm;
    right: 0cm;
    height: 2cm;
    /** Extra personal styles **/
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5cm;
}

/** Define the footer rules **/
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0cm;
    left: 0cm;
    right: 0cm;
    height: 2cm;

    /** Extra personal styles **/
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5cm;
}
footer .pagenum:before {
    content: counter(page);
}
</style>
```

In Body Tag add HEADER and FOOTER tag and wrap the main content in main tag

```
<header>
    This is a header
</header>

<footer>
<div class="pagenum-container">Page <span class="pagenum"></span></div>
</footer>
<main>
    <div>Main content goes here </div>
</main>
```

Reference site- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/687/how-to-configure-a-header-and-footer-in-dompdf

Comment: This was of help. Though how do i repeat only footer, Thanks